# The rates that i have given in if and else statements do not add up as they should

Tags: java

I have made a simple Tax Calculator that will calculate your tax differently if your single or married. I am using JOptionPane as this is a requirement and I am also needing to not put all my code within the main method, I have to use methods outside the main method but within the same constructor class which I have made two one for the single rate and one method for the married rate.

I have to be able to allow a user to input whether they are single or married and to be able to enter their income in. I have hardcoded the double variables though for each singe or married limit.
.

When I run the program it has no errors but it always returns the same result of 10% of any value I enter does not matter if it is above the single or married limit and I am unsure why this is occurring any help be appreciated.

I have tried setting the variables in each method and also tried placing all variables outside the methods (which I been told I can't do but was testing if it made a difference it didn't)

this is one method which I have repeated on the second method so not much point posting both

```
    public void single() {
        income = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your income ($)"));
        if (income <= singleLimit)  { // singleLimit = 32000 (mentioned in the comments)
            tax1 = rate1 * income; // rate1 = 0.10
        }   else    {
            tax1 = rate1 * singleLimit; 
            tax2 = rate2 * (income - singleLimit); // rate2 = 0.25
        }
        double totalTax = tax1 + tax2;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Taxable income for a single person wil be $" + totalTax );

    }
```

I would expect the output for a single with an income of 20,000 = 2,000
I would expect the output for a single with an income of 40,000 = 6,000

Comment: have you debugged your code? what is the value of singleLimit?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add that single limit is 32000, there are no errors showing if that's what you mean it is simply not giving the right output expected, i am wondering if I am missing one line of code

Comment: what are the values for rate1 and rate2, and what are the results you do get?

Comment: rate1 = 0.10
rate2 = 0.25

Income is a user input

Comment: tax1 and tax2 should be **local** variables, declared in the method, and both initialized to 0. But anyway, you need to learn to debug your code. Execute the lines of code one by one, and inspect the values of the variables. At the very least, add println() statements to know what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the help I am only just starting to learn so any advice is appreciated

Comment: shouldn't the outcome for 40000 be 5200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems alright. Try this and see if it works. There are no changes as such; I have just initialized some variables:

```
public void single() {
    double singleLimit = 32000.0; // making it double because your income is in double
    double tax1 = 0.0, tax2 = 0.0, totalTax = 0.0; // declaring all tax variables as local variables

    income = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your income ($)"));

    if (income <= singleLimit)  {
        tax1 = rate1 * income;
    } else {
        tax1 = rate1 * singleLimit;
        tax2 = rate2 * (income - singleLimit);
    }
    double totalTax = tax1 + tax2;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Taxable income for a single person wil be $" + totalTax );
}
```

Comment: Modo that worked a charm i had actually just tested it with them being local variables and it seems to work just great. Thanks heaps this can be marked as solved